# Google sheets - select multiple columns for data validation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new on google spreadsheets, and I'm having this little problem:

I want to create a project manager with an external spreadsheet just for customer-info. In my "main-hub" sheet, I have created a dropdown menu on B11 which copys the customer names from the extrenal sheet. That works fine.

Now the problem I am trying to solve: I want to keep the drop-down menu on B11, i dont want to add any new drop down menus. Whenever I select an item from the menu on B11, additional information about the customer should be inserted into different cells in different columns. Example:

| __________ B11 __________ | __________ J11 __________ | __________ K11 __________ |

```
        Selected Name         dynamicly inserted data 1      dynamicly inserted data 2
```

Please keep in mind, I really don't want to add any new drop down menu, I want to keep only this one for the names of the customers.

Comment: Could you explain how is your data laid out in your "external spreadsheet". This seems like a very straightforward use of [`VLOOKUP`]()https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en or [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) for that matter. But maybe you have asked this because your data is laid in multiple sheets and that would need a custom Apps Script function. Please post also how have you done the dropdown.

Comment: I have created an example, so that you can see what i want to accomplish. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11bKQOuUmPqb1AB6dGZNTEdHxv43B0gOpgx9PvL4Qvys/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is "VLOOKUP". This is a Formula where you can define a specific range and select the part you want to display. I've edited your spreadsheet.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;'Customers static'!$A$2:$C$5;2;FALSE);"")
```

- IFERROR Value, [value if error]
- VLOOKUP Search key, area, index, is sorted

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!! Does this also dynamicly change the range  , when i add or remove a row?

Comment: No you need to change the range on your own. If you add one row, just modify this part "$A$2:$C$5" to "$A$2:$C$6" or whatever range you're using.

You can just use "$A$2:$C" If you dont have anything else in A,B,C. So you don't need to edit the range.

Comment: Ok I understand. You see, I created a project management system for my company. Within that management sytsem I created 2 sheets. One sheet for monitoring the workflow within certain projects and one dedicated sheet just for adding in new clients. I'd then use your solution to fill in those client information. The sheet will grow one row for each project almost every day. Because of this i need a dynamic way of expanding your formula. I hope I was able to explain myself properly. If that isnt the case, I can edit my examplesheet accordingly to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have not solved your answer. I have created a new sheet in your spreadsheet showing you a possible answer.

#### Possible solution

Basically you can have a **dynamically expandable sheet with** the use of **[`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en).**

Which is kind of basically repeat this operation for the whole range. In this case you just would need to put one formula for each column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A;'Customers static'!A2:D;2;FALSE)))
```

Look how instead of using a single value for `VLOOKUP` you are using **the whole range** and ARRAYFORMULA will handle that. Therefore you just need to write **the formula at the top of each column**, **changing the index** for every single column in the original data.

[image: Working example of ARRAYFORMULA]

You can take a look in the *Raserhin's help* on **[the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11bKQOuUmPqb1AB6dGZNTEdHxv43B0gOpgx9PvL4Qvys/edit#gid=2119606825) you have provided.**